# Find The Available Seat Number

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically below is how my table in sql looks like, I need to find the available seat number in each room. When the time leave is null it means there still people in it if there is a time, which mean the person has already leave.

'Room' Table

| roomNo | seatNum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 4 | 25 |
| 5 | 10 |

'People' Table

| ID | RoomNo | TimeLeave |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 15:47:20 |
| 102 | 5 | NULL |
| 103 | 4 | 15:40:20 |
| 104 | 2 | NULL |
| 105 | 2 | NULL |

So How can i make the query output to something like below

| RoomNo | AvailableSeatNum | NotAvailable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 0 |
| 2 | 18 | 2 |
| 3 | 10 | 0 |
| 4 | 25 | 0 |
| 5 | 9 | 1 |

I tried doing sql like

```
SELECT room.roomNo,room.seatNum-count(people.id), count(people.id)
FROM room,people
WHERE room.roomNo=people.roomNo AND Timeleave is NULL
GROUP BY room.roomNo
```

But the results is only those room which are OCCUPIED ONLY

| RoomNo | AvailableSeatNum | NotAvailable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 18 | 2 |
| 5 | 9 | 1 |

Comment: not really sure what you mean, Im still new to sql, can you explain more about it?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: This is a strange data model.  People can only ever go into one room?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of what you have now (an implicit `INNER JOIN`).

As @FaNo_FN pointed out, the 2nd and 3rd column of your desired result are a bit trickier than I first thought. You want to count `NULL` `TimeLeave` rows in each group - `COUNT(*) - COUNT(people.TimeLeave)` - but only for all the rows that are part of the join (where, for example, `people.roomNo` is not `NULL`).

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    room.roomNo,
    room.seatNum - IF(people.roomNo IS NULL, 0, COUNT(*) - COUNT(people.TimeLeave)),
    IF(people.roomNo IS NULL, 0, COUNT(*) - COUNT(people.TimeLeave))
FROM room
LEFT JOIN people
ON room.roomNo = people.roomNo
GROUP BY room.roomNo, room.seatNum
```

Feel free to study up on different types of `JOIN`s: [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/6367213)

Comment: WHERE is considered as a INNER JOIN ?

Comment: Well, `WHERE` itself is just a keyword. See [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44917/6367213) for more info.

Comment: @Dream your "implicit inner join" is this part `FROM room,people`. By specifying two table objects to `SELECT FROM`, you are implying you want them joined.

Answer (score 0):

I hardly find any reason to use the old comma-join and you might never achieve your desired result if you stick to it. Try this query:

```
SELECT r.roomno,
       MAX(r.seatNum)-SUM(CASE WHEN p.roomno IS NULL THEN 0 WHEN p.roomno IS NOT NULL AND p.TimeLeave IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS AvailableSeatNum,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.roomno IS NULL THEN 0 WHEN p.roomno IS NOT NULL AND p.TimeLeave IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS NotAvailable
FROM room AS r
LEFT JOIN people AS p
ON r.roomNo=p.roomNo
GROUP BY r.roomno;
```

My mind is actually not in excellent shape right now so this is what I can come up. I'll attempt to break it down and explain to you one by one but I may miss a thing or two to mention. Anyways:

1. Change from comma-join to use `JOIN`; and in this particular problem, use `LEFT JOIN`. I'm talking about your query part here `.. FROM room,people ..`.
2. Assign aliases to your table `.. room AS r ...`. These are just for readability purposes and especially useful for long table names. Once you've assign and alias, you can use it throughout the query. Just don't use duplicate aliases.
3. According to your example data, it seems like the value for `seatNum` is fixed so I used `MAX()` to cater [sql_mode=only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). There are other methods too like [ANY_VALUE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) but I'll just use `MAX()` for this example. However, I assume that you're `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` is turned off but if it's not, consider these methods.

In the `SELECT`, I've made a bunch of `CASE` expression condition to get the calculation according to your desired result. I attempt to make it work without using sub-query but I personally would prefer to use a sub-query at least; it's easier for me to read. What I mean is:

```
SELECT rp.roomno, 
       MAX(rp.seatnum)-SUM(rp.cval) AS AvailableSeatNum, 
       SUM(rp.cval) AS NotAvailable
FROM
(SELECT r.roomno, r.seatNum, p.id, p.TimeLeave,
       CASE WHEN p.roomno IS NULL THEN 0 
            WHEN p.roomno IS NOT NULL AND p.TimeLeave IS NOT NULL THEN 0 
       ELSE 1 END AS cval 
FROM room AS r
LEFT JOIN people AS p
ON r.roomNo=p.roomNo) rp
GROUP BY rp.roomno;
```

With a sub-query, I only need to do `CASE` expression once and then later just refer to it on the outer query. Let's focus on the `CASE`:

```
CASE WHEN p.id IS NULL THEN 0 
            WHEN p.id IS NOT NULL AND p.TimeLeave IS NOT NULL THEN 0 
       ELSE 1 END AS cval
```

`WHEN p.roomno IS NULL THEN 0` is checking the result of `LEFT JOIN` between `room` and `people` table. Since, `people` table don't have `roomno=3`, it will return `p.roomno` as `NULL`, hence `CASE` will change that to 0.

`WHEN p.roomno IS NOT NULL AND p.TimeLeave IS NOT NULL THEN 0` checks if the `LEFT JOIN` have matches of `roomno` for both table, it will return value for `p.roomno` and if `p.TimeLeave` have value instead of `NULL`, means it's occupied.

and `ELSE 1` is just telling that if any of the condition above is not met, return 1. With the values returned between `0` and `1`, you'll just have to do `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()` at the outer query (since `COUNT()` will count how many rows).

I hope the explanation is easy to understand. Here is a fiddle for reference:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=17b88d7de91f4135f6bc1a795ff2a86e

Answer (score -1):

It's fine , desired result u wish

```
select Peoples.RoomNo, Room.seatNum - COUNT(Peoples.RoomNo), COUNT(Peoples.RoomNo) as NotAvailable from Room inner join Peoples on Room.roomNo = Peoples.RoomNo 
where Peoples.TimeLeave is null
group by Peoples.RoomNo, Room.seatNum
union all
select Room.RoomNo, Room.seatNum, 0 from Room where Room.roomNo not in (select Peoples.RoomNo from Peoples)
union all
select Peoples.RoomNo, Room.seatNum, 0 from Room inner join Peoples on Room.roomNo = Peoples.RoomNo 
where Peoples.TimeLeave is not null
group by Peoples.RoomNo, Room.seatNum
```